# Storing a file to internal storage and reading it

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is store a JSON file as a string in internal storage to access it later. The reasoning behind this is to not have to access the server on every request, as this data is constant. Once it is stored once, it doesn't have to be retrieved again unless there is some sort of update. File storage isn't something I've done before, and I was hoping someone could give me a hand. My current code is throwing a null pointer exception at this line:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
```

My code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] runeId) {
        String url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/rune/" +  runeId[0] + "?api_key=" + api_key;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject runeInfo = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        String jsonString = runeInfo.toString();
        String fileName = "runeInfo";
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
        String readJson = null;

        if(!runesCached) {
            Log.d("Cache", "Caching File");
            try {

                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                os.write(jsonString.getBytes());
                os.close();
                Log.d("Cache", "Cache Complete");
                runesCached = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String name = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis;

            File storedRuneInfo = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
            fis =  new FileInputStream(storedRuneInfo);

            fis.read(readJson.getBytes());
            JSONObject storedJson = new JSONObject(readJson);

            try {
                name = storedJson.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir().toString(), fileName);
```

getFilesDir() returns a File, not a String, which the File class constructor takes as a parameter.

getFilesDir()toString() should return something like /data/data/com.your.app/

EDIT:

This gives the same error. How about:

```
try {
    FileWriter fstream;
    BufferedWriter out;

    fstream = new FileWriter(getFilesDir() + "/" + "filename");
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(jsonString.getBytes());
    out.close();

} catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: This results in the same error. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: That seems to have worked great. New error is with reading the saved file at this line:                 File storedRuneInfo = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

Comment: How about fis =  new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "/" + "filename"); instead?

Comment: With that change it continues to crash, now at that piece of code instead.